# Script para detectar números primos em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Resolvi criar um *script* para detectar números primos, mas no objetivo de realmente entender sobre o que estou fazendo eu criei algo do zero, algo que pensei.

A princípio meu programa funcionou, porém notei que ele "trava" em números grandes, acima de 5 dígitos, como se estivesse consumindo toda a memória do PC, depois de um tempo ele destrava e enfim mostra o resultado, não sei se isso é normal. Enfim, gostaria de melhorar este código, afim de compreender de forma bem didática o que estou fazendo, se for possível, alguém que me ajude a visualizar o motivo do "travamento", e a sua correção.
Segue:

```
numero = int(input('Digite um numero:'))

div = 0

cont = numero

while cont >= 1:

    if numero % cont == 0:

    div += 1

     cont += -1

if div < 2 or div > 2:

    print('Não é primo!')

elif div == 2:

    print('É primo')
```

Outra solução que pensei foi esta, mas trava do mesmo jeito:

```
numero = int(input('Digite um numero:'))

div = 0

cont = numero

while div < 2:

    if numero % cont == 0:

     div += 1

     cont += -1

if div < 2 or div > 2:

    print('Não é primo!')

elif div == 2:

     print('É primo')
```

Me desculpem, ainda não sei postar códigos corretamente neste site, espero que consigam visualizar as identações...

Answer (score 1):

É normal ele demorar com números muito grandes, se você colocar o número 1000  por exeplo quer dizer que vai ser 1000 divisões e mais de mil comparações com o if... você poderia melhorar o desempenho dividindo esse numero apenas pelos números que vão até a metade dele, o mil por exemplo não existe divisor maior que 500 que é sua metade... então você poderia melhorar o desempenho em 50% já que seria necessário fazer apenas metade dos cálculos e comparações no loop

Comment: A sugestão "você poderia melhorar o desempenho dividindo esse numero apenas pelos números que vão até a metade dele" é muito boa. Se em vez de for até a metade for só até a raiz quadrada, o código ficará ainda mais otimizado.

Comment: Verdade, seria bem mais otimizado, desconheço essa propriedade das raízes quadradas, você tem link de algum conteúdo que fale sobre isso?